# ThisWorkbook Workbook_Open fails to show userform if Excel or Word already open

Tags: excel, vba, office365, userform

I use Office365. I have an Excel file called Test.xlsm which contains a userform named frmMain.
In the ThisWorkbook object and then in the Workbook_Open event I have the following code:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       Worksheets("Main").Activate
       frmMain.Show
    End Sub
```

It is meant to launch (show) the frmMain userform every time the Test.xlsm file opens.
However, if another Excel or Word file is already open, the frmMain user form fails to launch/show.
Is there a way to have an Excel or Word file already open and still be able to launch and use the Test.xlsm file and its userform frmMain ? is this a problem with Office365?

UPDATE:

Also tried setting the application security to low in case it was defaulting to msoAutomationSecurityByUI:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

dim frm As frmMain
Dim secAutomation As MsoAutomationSecurity

set frm = New frmMain
secAutomation = Application.AutomationSecurity

Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
Worksheets("Main").Activate
frmMain.Show

End Sub
```

UPDATE:

Also tried placing this on a stand alone module (not in ThisWorkbook):

```
Private Sub runForm()
   frmMain.Show
End Sub
```

Then calling it like this from the ThisWorkbook > Workbook_Open event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.OnTime VBA.Now, "name of file '!runForm.runForm"
End Sub
```

With all other Excel closed, this also opens Test.xlsm and the userform, but when an .xlsx is already open then it is the same problem - opened the file but it didn't open the userform.

Comment: this doesn't answer your question, but you should really be working with an instance of your form and not the default instance. [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186649/vba-userform-new-instance)

Comment: Do you mean allowing users to open an instance of the userform manually? I need the form to open as soon as the file is opened.

Comment: No, I mean creating a `new` instance of your form rather than using the predeclared, default instance. My suggestion/answer shows how this could be done.

Comment: Are you sure that `Application.EnableEvents` was not set to `False` by already open workbook(s)? Try this. Type `Application.EnableEvents = True` in Immediate Window in VBE before you open the workbook. Now check...

Comment: Yes, the other workbooks are plain .xlsx, no other macros ran before launching Test.xlsm. EnableEvents default would be True. In any case I just added Application.EnableEvents = True before frm.Show in Workbook_Open event. Launched  Test.xlsm with another plain .xlsx workbook open in the background (blank workbook). Test.xlsm opened, but frm.Show did not run and the userform did not show.

Comment: No. You need to type that in immediate window. Not in workbook open event.

Comment: Opened the VBE on another workbook. Typed Application.EnableEvents = True into the Immediate window. Launched Test.xlsm and... it opened and launched the form! BUT. Closed Test.xlsm. Left the VBE and the other workbook open. Launched Test.xlsm again and.... it opened the workbook but not the form. Same problem as before.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Created a xlsm file named test, with a form inside. Used your code. Even if I have another Excel file opened, test.xlsm works as expected (activates main sheet and shows the userform).

Comment: remove `frmMain.Show` from  `Workbook_Open()` and move it to main worksheet module using  `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When another Workbook is opened, Workbook_Open events do not fire properly for newly opened workbooks. This is a bug.

One way to solve this is to take advantage of a Custom RibbonUI Object so that you can have an event firing when the Workbook is opened.

This is not simple to set up but you only have to do it once. There are 3 steps needed:

**1) Set up a Friend method in the ThisWorkbook object**
Write the following code inside the **ThisWorkbook** module:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_openAlreadyRan As Boolean

Friend Sub FireOpenEventIfNeeded(Optional dummyVarToMakeProcHidden As Boolean)
    If Not m_openAlreadyRan Then Workbook_Open
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
End Sub
```

Note a few things:
a) the dummy parameter is needed to hide the method from the **Macros** box (Alt+F8)
b) the method is declared as **Friend** so it is only accessible to this project
c) a boolean variable is needed (m_openAlreadyRan). This will be used later at stage 3

**2) Embed a CustomRibbon into your Workbook**
First we need some code to call the method created at step 1.
Create a standard module in your Workbook and call it **CustomUI**. Add the following code to the **CustomUI** module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub InitRibbon(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    ThisWorkbook.FireOpenEventIfNeeded
End Sub
```

This method needs to be called when the Ribbon is initialized. In other words, this method is a callback method used by the Ribbon.

This is the tricky part. This can be done is several ways and you can find some tools on the web. However, I will show you how to do it manually:
a) Close and Save your Workbook

b) Download an archiver program if you don't use one. I use [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) which is free

c) Open the archiver and browse to your Workbook folder

d) Right-click the Workbook and choose **Open inside**
[image]

e) Create a folder called **customUI**. You will have noticed that the Workbook file is actually an achive of files
[image]

f) Open Notepad or any text editor and create a new file with the following xml:

```xml
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="InitRibbon"></customUI>
```

Notice that the name of the **onLoad** callback matches the method created in VBA i.e. **InitRibbon**

g) Save text file (anywhere) as **customUI.xml** (make sure you don't have double extension (e.g. .xml.txt)

h) Drag and drop the .xml file in the customUI folder inside the archiver
[image]

i) Go back one level and open the **_rels** folder. You should see a **.rels** file[image]

j) Edit the **.rels** file (right-click then Edit should open a Notepad)

k) Add the xml:

```xml
<Relationship Id="rId10" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="customUI/customUI.xml"/>
```

This needs to go **before** the ending `</Relationships>` tag. Not after.
I've used rId10 but you can look at all the other rId numbers in the file and choose the next available one. **Make sure you do not duplicate an existing rId**

l) Save your edits to the file and exit the archive while making sure you save the archive edits as well (you should be prompted if you use 7-Zip with an Ok/Cancel box)

m) Close the archiver. You're done with it

**3) Set up the Workbook_Open event**
We need to take into account the boolean created at step 1 (so that we don't run same code twice) and the protected state of the window view.
Replace the code at step 1 (in ThisWorkbook) with this:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_openAlreadyRan As Boolean
Private m_isOpenDelayed As Boolean

Friend Sub FireOpenEventIfNeeded(Optional dummyVarToMakeProcHidden As Boolean)
    If Not m_openAlreadyRan Then Workbook_Open
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    If m_isOpenDelayed Then
        m_isOpenDelayed = False
        InitWorkbook
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    m_openAlreadyRan = True
    Dim objProtectedViewWindow As ProtectedViewWindow
    '
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objProtectedViewWindow = Application.ProtectedViewWindows(Me.Name)
    On Error GoTo 0
    '
    m_isOpenDelayed = Not (objProtectedViewWindow Is Nothing)
    If Not m_isOpenDelayed Then InitWorkbook
End Sub

Private Sub InitWorkbook()
    If VBA.Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        MsgBox "This Workbook requires Excel 2007 or later!", vbCritical, "Closing"
        Me.Close False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    '
    With New frmMain
        .Show
        'Other code
        '
        '
        '
    End With
End Sub
```

Notice the following:
a) The **_Open** event code is delayed to the **_Activate** event in case Window View is protected
b) Both **_Open** and **_Activate** point to the **InitWorkbook** method.This is where you add the code you need to run when the workbook opens
c) **m_openAlreadyRan** is set to True in the **_Open** event so that the **FireOpenEventIfNeeded** method does not call **_Open** unnecessarily (i.e. when the bug is not happening because there are no other books open)
d) I've used a **New** instance of **frmMain** exactly as **@ArcherBird** mentioned. It is considered bad practice to use the global instance of the form by calling `frmMain.Show`. Also, instead of `With New frmMain` you could just create a variable:

```
Dim f As New frmMain
f.Show
```

Comment: I followed all the steps and your solution resolved the problem 100%. For future users just a tiny note that the module on Step 2 needs to be named 'customUI' as referenced on the .xlm not 'CustomUI' . Many thanks Cristian, excellent!

Comment: @Badda_Bing    Glad it worked. The name of the standard module doesn't matter. Could be anything. The InitRibbon method is called regardless of the module name. However, the folder name and file name /customUI/customUI.xml in the file archive must match with the xml fragment added at step 2) sub-step k) in the .rels file. They could also be named differently as long as they match.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can move your opening logic out of the `ThisWorkbook` object and into a Module with a `Auto_Open` method:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Dim frm as frmMain
   Set frm = new frmMain

   Worksheets("Main").Activate
   frm.Show
End Sub
```

Edit:
Because I'm not sure why the ThisWorkbook.Workbook_Open event wouldn't work, I just tried it for myself and it worked fine for me... But let me know if switching to `Auto_Open` worked?

Comment: I used your code on an Auto_Open module (outside of the ThisWorkbook module) and it didn't work i.e. nothing happened. I used it in the ThisWorkbook Workbook_Open event module and it works 'sometimes'!. Btw I am testing this with another unrelated Excel file open. Sometimes the Test.xlsm will open and the frmMain will appear and other times it won't! I've no idea what is going on...

Comment: Is your form modal? Any chance it could be opening off-screen or something?

Comment: It is definitely Modal. But I think you may be onto something. Actually, the times when Test.xlsm is launched and the userform fails to appear (because there is another Excel file open) Test.xlsm still opens and shows the "Main" sheet (just not the userform) and yes, it behaves as if it was in vbModeless mode i.e. I can click around on the "Main" sheet and select cells etc.. but when the Test.xlsm opens properly i.e. launching the userform, I could not click around on the sheet behind, etc.. i.e. proper Modal mode.

Comment: @Badda_Bing, curious if you could post (if you have anything in it) the form's initialize code?

Comment: At first I thought it could be something there too, so I commented out the UserForm_Initialize module. Unfortunately it makes no difference. I've also tried setting the app security to low in case it was defaulting to disable macros launched from the Open event. I'm  updating the question above to show the code.

Comment: @Badda_Bing, if the form is modal, and you are able to click around the worksheet - I would think this means the form is not being created. Did you try instantiating a new object of type frmMain and calling `.Show` on that? Perhaps also you could try putting a `MsgBox` pop up in your form Initialization to see if the form is ever initialized at all and crashes, or if it is truly never even trying to execute the `.Show`?

Comment: Yes, I used the code you posted earlier to create an instance of the form when the file opens. Then I placed a simple MsgBox message in the UserForm_Initialize module and it did not run. The file just opened but the form never initialized.

Comment: @Badda_Bing well, I’m just about out of guesses here. Could you try also putting a msgbox in the Workbook_Open event to see if this is truly being executed? Is there any place in code (in either this WB or any of the other already open WBs) that might turn off Application.EnableEvents?

Comment: Yep, I did that now as requested and the MsgBox ran just fine. I'm pretty lost myself with this one - I appreciate the help. Beginning to think it may be some sort of issue with Office365 running on the remote desktop. Shouldn't be - I've tons of macros that run just fine. Seems to be just userforms. Are you getting the same issue? i.e. if you create a basic form, then with another Excel open launch the file with the form with the frm.Show in the Workbook_Open module. Would you get the same problem or am I going insane here..?.

Comment: @Badda_Bing I have not been able to recreate the problem on my computer. I’m running O365 x64 on W10

Comment: In theory so am I, O365 x64 W10, Excel version 1908(Build 11929.20838 Click-to-Run). Just to note I'm working on a remote desktop/VM, but being O365 that shouldn't matter at all. I'll keep looking, cheers.