# WorkbookOpen event sometimes not firing - event used for set global variables

Tags: excel, vba

I have a really basic problem with my projects and I would like to know which approach is the best. I like to use (hated) globals, **only for a few** the most important objects in a workbook.

I am declaring e.g. my *data tables* in a such way:

```
'@Folder("Main")
Option Exclicit

Public tblDatabase As Listobject   
Public tblReport As Listobject   

Sub setMyTables()
    Set tblDatabase = wsDatabase.ListObjects("tDatabase")
    Set tblReport = wsReport.ListObjects("tReport")
End Sub
```

In the past I used this macro before actions on the table, e.g.:

```
Function getIdFromDatabaseTable() As Variant
   
   ' set variable-object to use
     setMyTables    <-- I used to table-setting-sub in every
                       macro which requires one of my table

   ' get ID from table
     Dim arr As Variant
         arr = tblDatabase.ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange.Value2
   
   ' assign array to function result
     getIdFromDataTable = arr

End Function
```

But why I had to begin almost every macro with calling *setMyTables()* macro? So I've started to use workbook open event to set my object variables:

```
[code in ordinary Module]

'@Folder("Main")
Option Exclicit

Public tblDatabase As Listobject   
Public tblReport As Listobject
```

And call *setMyTables()* macro in *Workbook_Open()* event code. And here my problem is:

[**TLTR**] Setting variable-objects in Workbook-Open event seems **unrielable**. It seems it is not firing sometimes. I am sure that no macro error would reset the project and 'clear' already set variables, because sometimes it throws error on the very first macro run. It is not working occasionally and I don't know what pattern behind it is, I send Excel workbooks to my clients, and it's hard to debug what's realy going on there.

**Additional comments**

I've just read that this could happen if file is not in trusted localizations, I would like get to know best approach to handle declaring the most used objects globally (if possible without modifying someones trusted folders or another local-PC settings).

I know that I can set a 'flag' bool variable such as wasWorkbookOpenEventFired, but I would have to call checking *function* or make *ifs* on almost every Sub or Function in a workbook. So I think it isn't good solution too. Thanks for hints!

Comment: You'd have more robust results if you define public functions which return a specific table, and use those instead of global variables.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/63328366/8488913](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63328366/8488913)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have more robust results if you define public functions which each return a specific table, and use those instead of global variables:

```
Function DatabaseTable() As ListObject
    Static rv As ListObject '<< cache the table here
    'if your code gets reset then this will just re-cache the table
    If rv Is Nothing then Set rv = wsDatabase.ListObjects("tDatabase")
    Set DatabaseTable = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Simply and genious. I forgot obvious things that (1) if there is no argument in the function, we can skip parantheses and (2) if the function return type is defined, the IDE intellisense is working the same way as with 'normal' typed variable. I just hope that this not reduces macro's performance speed a lot. Thank you very much!