# SheetBeforeDoubleClick is working in my Excel but not working in others machine for Excel macOS

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have developed an addin for MacOS Excel where the SheetBeforeDoubleClick is working fine in my Excel but when I am sharing it to my teammates its not working. I checked system configurations, Both Excel and MacOS versions are same for me and my teamates.

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents MyAppEvents As Application
Private Sub MyAppEvents_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
'MsgBox "Double clicked..."
On Error GoTo doubleclickerr

If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True Then
    'MsgBox "Can not perform Zoom-in on Empty cells."
ElseIf IsNumeric(ActiveCell) = True Then
    'MsgBox "Can not perform Zoom-in on Numeric cells."
Else
    Application.StatusBar = "Zooming in…"
    MainModule.ZoomIn
    Application.StatusBar = ""
End If
Cancel = True
Exit Sub
doubleclickerr:
   MsgBox "error in double click: " & Error
End Sub
```

I tried debuging in others machines but the control is not coming to Event method(SheetBeforeDoubleClick).  MyAppEvent is initialization done in `Workbook_Open()` method of **ThisWorkbook** object. code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
MainModule.App_Open

End Sub
```

And in MainModule

```
Option Private Module
Public AppEvent As New EventClass
Sub App_Open()
    Set AppEvent.MyAppEvents = Application
End Sub
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Update:

I have fixed this issue and uploaded answer to this post.

Comment: @DecimalTurn, I am running Excel on Mac. This project is only for Mac users.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `Application.EnableEvents` is set to `True` for the other user/teammate.

Also check if `Workbook_Open()` is actually firing. Add a `Debug.Print "Open"` line inside the event and then close and reopen the file and check the Immediate window. If it does not fire (i.e. nothing gets printed in the Immediate window) then check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63134625/thisworkbook-workbook-open-fails-to-show-userform-if-excel-or-word-already-open/63328366#63328366) I wrote a while ago.

Comment: Nice to know your referred post.

Comment: I dont have `Application.EnableEvents` in my codebase. May be its because I am working Excel for MacOS. I did some research and i got to know that by default the `Application.EnableEvents` is `True`. I am sharing my XLAM file to users. @Christian

Comment: @meMadhav You have no guarantee that the other user has ```Application.EnableEvents``` equal to ```True``` because they have the ability to change this for their application either directly by running ```Application.EnableEvents = False``` or if some other code running on their Excel does this. You can easily test this on their computer by typing ```?Application.EnableEvents``` in their Immediate Window in the VBE and then pressing Enter from keyboard. For example, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AZgU.png) is a print screen I made on my Excel for Mac.

Comment: @meMadhav If events are indeed on then you must check if the Open event is actaully running. Like I said, just add a ```Debug.Print "Open"``` line in the ```Workbook_Open()``` event and then close and open the file and check the Immediate window to see if anything printed. Alternatively substitute with ```MsgBox "Open"``` if you don't want to bother using the Immediate window.

Comment: @CristianBuse, The `Workbook_Open()` is always running. I checked with `MsgBox` inside the event.

Comment: And About the `Application.EnableEvents = False` thing, Even though `Workbook_Open()` is running at the beginning and still not working but When I am running `Workbook_Open()` again then it's working. But we cant ask users to go and manually run it.

Comment: @meMadhav If ```Workbook_Open()``` is always running then there must be a problem with the code that you're running. It will be easier to step through line by line and see what's going on. To do this you must first remove the VB Project password, then add a ```Stop``` statement as the first line of the ```Workbook_Open()``` event. Then save and re-open the file. Once the the event fires the code will break on the ```Stop``` line and yop will be able to step through using Alt+F8 to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to a public module in your addin. It will run even if user has events turned off:

```
Public Sub Auto_Open()
    Application.EnableEvents=True
    'Do Other Stuff
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After so much of debugging, rework and head banging, I have figured out the issue. In my xlam file, there was a `compilation error`. We have one **CheckBox** and in its action method, additional parameter `pressed As Boolean` was missing. Due to this compiltime error, It was not working in few machines.

```
Sub chkOptSuppMiss_onAction(control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean)

    
End Sub
```

I figured out this issue by removing last changes in my code. **CheckBox** was one of the last changes i made.

**Thank you all for your time and responses.**